# Powershell Passing parameter to MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument

Tags: mongodb, powershell, parameters, bson

Can I pass a string parameter to MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument?

For the same scripts following, 1) returns document and 2) returns null.

1)

```
$query = new-object MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument("item", "car")
$found = $mongoCollection.FindOne($query)
```

2)

```
$comp = "car"
function Get-Document($comp){

    $query = new-object MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument("item", $comp)
    $found = $mongoCollection.FindOne($query)
    return $found
}

$result = Get-Document $comp
Write-host $result
```

Comment: Is `$mongoCollection` initialized properly? Where do you call `Get-Document`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience with MongoDB, but I don't see why the second code snippet shouldn't work if the first one does. I think the problem is that your function doesn't actually return anything.

PowerShell functions return all non-captured output to the caller, so you need to remove the assignment `$found = ...` to make the function return the result (and of course you need to call it, too):

```psh
$comp = "car"

function Get-Document($item){
    $query = new-object MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument("item", $item)
    $mongoCollection.FindOne($query)
}

$found = Get-Document $comp
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I added return statement and still the same result

Comment: @Taewan I still don't see the function being called anywhere in your code. Also, try renaming the function parameter to avoid scoping issues.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I added function call. The function works well when I don't use parameter, as mentioned at 1). MongoCollection initialized well. The only change between 1) and 2) is I pass "car" as a parameter instead of typing it

Comment: @Taewan Did you try changing the parameter name as I suggested (see updated answer)?

Comment: Yes. It worked. It turns out I put "Car" instead of "car". I really appreciate your help Ansgar!